# Can't call COM-object-method with parameter of type Array

Tags: c#, com

I have a COM class with a method with the following signature:

```
public class MyComClass {
    public void SomeMethod(Array myarray) { }
}
```

Now in an other project I call this registered COM class using the following code block:

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ProgIdOf.MyComClass");
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
object[] contentOfMyArray = new object[] { "Hello World" };
t.InvokeMember("SomeMethod", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, o, new object[] { contentOfMyArray });
```

I'm trying to pass the `contentOfMyArray` as the first parameter to the `SomeMethod`-method. But when I try that I get this exception:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

The method itself does not throw this exception, I checked that.
When I change the signature to `public void SomeMethod(object[] myarray) { }` or use no array at all and pass the values it works perfectly. When I create an object of the type `Array` like this:

```
Array contentOfMyArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), 1);
contentOfMyArray.SetValue("Hello World", 0);
```

and pass it as a parameter it still throws this exception.

I read a lot of stuff about *marshalling* but I couldn't get it to work.
Btw. I cant use a "normal" array like `object[]`, I have to use the `Array` type.

I hope you can help, I'm not very experienced with COM at all. Thank you!

Comment: .NET's Array as is will not be passed as a COM array (SAFEARRAY). Try do declare it like this instead: `SomeMethod([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)] Array myarray)`

Comment: Imagine I have no control over the signature of `SomeMethod` then it's basicly impossible with C# to call this function?

Comment: In fact, I just checked as is and it works for me. My class is declared as [ComVisible(true)] +  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]. Are you using an old .NET framework?